# Upgrade Laptop CPU

Tags: processor

So, I've got an Asus k53sv laptop with an i7 2630qm processor and want to upgrade to an i7 3820qm. Their sockets and power consumption are the same, as listen on Intel's website, so I don't see why it wouldn't work. Only concern is whether a driver mismatch might occur. Do you think this would work?

Comment: Your laptop's CPU is probably soldered to the motherboard..., meaning you'd have to have extreme technical knowledge of how it all works, and have the tools to desolder the original. I don't think it would work very well.

Comment: Update & clarification: the i7 3820qm is a different generation and is not supported by my chipset. I have a Sandy Bridge HM65 and 3820qm is Ivy Bridge. Also, when checking my motherboard specs with CPU Z, it has an rPGA processor socket, meaning the processor is removable (unlike the BGA socket which means the CPU is soldered to the motherboard). There is however, the i7 2860qm which is sandy bridge hm65 and has the same power consumption (45W). So the new question is would the i7 2860qm work?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't think you could fit a Ivy Bridge into a Sandy Bridge motherboard, but I don't know much about the older architectures, so check the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than hardware issues (whether the CPU is soldered, and whether the socket is the same), software/bios/driver issues should not be a problem if the two CPUs are from the same generation (sometimes it even works with different generations of CPUs).

I've done it on a Thinkpad T61 a few years ago, as well as on a(n old) Mac Mini recently (in both cases upgrading to a Core 2 Duo).  If the CPU is cheap enough (as is the case when the CPU is an old model), I find it's definitely worth the trouble.

Comment: I replaced the processor and it was a success. Thanks.

Comment: @thatguyoverthere, can you confirm you have/had an i7-3820QM working in an Asus K53SV? I have a K53SC and was wondering if I could also upgrade to an i7-3820QM...

Comment: Hi there, as far as I can remember, i7-3xxx series wont fit a i7-2xxx socket. I did however fit the  i7-2860hq on my Asus K53SV. It's been running fine every since I did it 2 years ago. 0 issues.

Answer (score 2):

It could work but i wouldn't recommend it.

First of all this will void your warrenty, second most laptops are not made to be upgraded. most laptops have there CPU and GPU soldered to the motherboard.  you may get heat issuse and you cooler might break or not bend back proberly if done wrong.
I don't think you can buy mobile CPU's on the consummer marked. maybe you should consider to upgrade to a new laptop. I personaly have a Gs60 Ghost from MSI and its great.

If you want your pc to be a bit faster maybe try installing an SSD.

If the TDP is the same and you are good in removing tiny screw and appying maybe some silicon glue you may be able to do it. as of drivers that shoulden't have to be a problem.I think your motherboard also needs to support it. I'm not a laptop hardware expert so keep that in mind.So keep that in mine.

acoring to intel the CPU is 568.00 dollars wich is expensive in my book for a gamble. if you manage to do it be sure to update this question.

Overall I wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Like mentioned [here on Tomsguide](http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-2309244/laptop-cpu.html), it won't work because you're dealing with different generations of intel processors (the i7 3XXX series and the older i7 2XXX series) using different types of sockets.

#### EDIT

(I didn't know you already had an ssd.)

It is possible to upgrade from a second generation i7 to another second generation i7. The performance increase from such a small upgrade is barely noticable and the risks are too high imho.

#### EDIT2

[Here is a list of laptop Passmark scores](https://www.cpubenchmark.net/laptop.html). Between the i7-2630qm and the i7-2860qm there's a difference of just 1730 points. That's a performance increase of about 30 percent (in real life performance the difference will be smaller, though).

Also can you mention where you generally use your laptop for? gaming, editing, browsing, etc.?

Comment: already got an SSD, totally worth it

Comment: gaming and compilation, mostly. While doing these all cores stay at their maximum turbo frequency. I've done all cleaning (physically and digitally) to increase performance but it seems processing power is the biggest problem at the moment.

Comment: This seems to be the best improvement after the SSD that does not require purchasing a new machine. I am still considering if it is worth it now, after the information you provided for me, thank you for which.